# Cleanup string for XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to Xml serialize a huge amount of strings which comes from different sources.

The problem is that the XmlSerializer throws an exception if the string contains the character the serializer can't handle.

Of course I've done the basic string normalization, but finding "bad" characters again and again. The latest 3 were: `'\a', '\0', '\u001f'`

Is there a way to remove all unsupported characters from the string or to let the XmlSerializer ignore them?

My current code is:

```
public static string CleanupStringForValidXMLExport(this string inputString)
{
    if (!inputString.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        //InvalidXMLCharacters
        return inputString.Remove(new[] { '\x1A', '\x1D', '\x0B', '\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x17', '\x18', '\a', '\0', '\u001f' })
            .RemoveMultipleWhiteSpaces()
            .ReplaceUmlauts()
            .ReplaceSpecialChars();
    }

    return inputString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Many characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) are considered invalid in XML even if they occur as entity references (eg. `#x0`). However, you can safely read them if you turn off character checking in the `XmlReader`:

```
new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false };
```

Please note that that this turns off character checking for entities only, and not for the invalid plain characters but you can convert them to entities in your pre-processing method so you can preserve everything.

Answer (score 0):

try this for remove invalid xml characters

```
  public static string CleanupStringForValidXMLExport(this string inputString)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char ch in inputString)
        {
            if (XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch))
                s.Append(ch);

        }

        return s;
    }
```